# How to get data from canvas using canvas.toDataURL()?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas and jsPDF for printing my html file.

when my html page has horizontal scroll at that time image is cutting i uses following code

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('ppm_portlet_data');
html2canvas(element[0]).then(function (canvas) {

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
    console.log(data); //this data is base64 and it is cutting my image 

);
```

The canvas's width and height is same as the element. But when i get it from canvas, it will be cut off. How to fix this?